# Is there any obfuscation in the communications between nodes?

Tags: monerod, privacy, kovri, i2p

If a dictatorship decided it wanted to block Monero, how easy or hard would it be at the ISP level? Does Monero have any built in obfuscation to counter censorship (of Monero use in general such as running a node, mining, or sending or receiving transactions) at the ISP level?

If no such obfuscation exists, what plans are there for users in countries such as China where bans for anything not tightly controlled by the government are common. Bitcoin is transparent, trackable, and censorable, so I do not consider that an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none, hence the work on https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/.

A government might make I2P itself illegal, though, and that'd be yet another hurdle. Tor has something to try to look like other traffic (pluggable transports), which could be adapted to Kovri in the future.

See [Why is it I2P (garlic routing) well suited for Monero (compared to possible alternatives)?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/why-is-it-i2p-garlic-routing-well-suited-for-monero-compared-to-possible-alte) for a recent list of why Kovri/I2P was chosen for Monero's future network level foundation.